# How to get the correct XPath for a column title using C# and selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-webdriver-c#

I have the following HTML

```
<label class="ms-Label headerText-269" title="Reference Id">Reference Id</label>
```

which I am trying to locate using XPath.
I have written the following which doesn't seem to work.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//title[contains(text(),'Reference Id']"));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@title, 'Reference Id')]";
```

Tip:

In the development tools of Chrome-based or Firefox-based browsers, you can actually type an XPath or CSS selector in the "find" box of the element inspector. Then copy the working finder into your code.

Comment: Thanks very much!